# No puedo agregar productos a mi treeview en python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

No puedo insertar los productos en la base de datos y tampoco figuran en el sistema, directamente no afecta en nada el botón al sistema, solo se cierra la ventana Toplevel y continua como si nada. Probé usar "mensajes de error", para detectar el problema pero no lo encuentro. adjunto el código.

```
def agregar_producto(self):
    # variables
    self.tabla_uno
    codigo = self.codigo.get()
    nombre = self.nombre_producto.get()
    cantidad = self.stock.get()
    tipo = self.tipo_producto.get()

    # conexión
    db = sqlite3.connect('PDVdamoonplay.db')
    conexion = db.cursor()
        
    # consulta
    if codigo and nombre and cantidad and tipo != '':
        query = conexion.execute('INSERT INTO productos VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)',[codigo, nombre, cantidad, tipo])
        db_rows = query
        self.ventana_agregar.destroy()
        self.cargar_productos()
        self.codigo.set('')
        self.nombre_producto.set('')
        self.stock.set('')
        self.tipo_producto.set('')
        for row in db_rows:
            self.tabla_uno.insert('', 0, text = row[codigo.get()], values = (row[nombre.get()],row[cantidad.get()],row[tipo.get()]))
            break
```

Comment: No se si tienes algún autocommit habilidado (por default sqlite no habilita el autocommit). Pero si está deshabilitado, te faltó enviar los datos a la base de datos con el comando `conexion.commit()`

Comment: Si me di cuenta mas tarde muchas gracias!.